# Rendering css and js files in flask?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I am using below html to render css and js files in flask template.

```
    <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/jquery.dropotron.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/jquery.scrollgress.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/skel.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/skel-layers.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/init.js') }}"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/skel.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/style.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/style-wide.css') }}">
```

But still I get error in command prompt as css not found that is the 404 error but css gets loaded in site and styling is shown on web page.
Why do i get the error then and my site is also responsive but since javascript doesn't get loaded css files are not changed.

Comment: Which files are causing the 404 errors?

Comment: CSS and Js files are causing error.The files above in code.

Comment: Try with a new browser, whether it to check already in cache.

Comment: I am not getting a mobile view and PC view simultaneously. If i get for mobile I don't get the PC view and vice versa.

Comment: Maybe you should give us your flask app's struct, so we can figure out where is wrong. And I wonder if your css files lying under the `static/css/` folders?

Comment: CSS files are under static/CSS/style.css